# Identify the function of a sequential circuit

Tags: circuit-design

I am working on the following question:
[image]

I managed to get the following answer is it correct?
    [image]

---

Is this correct? It has 16 stated and also has the count enable.
[image]

Comment: Almost, except for the last line in your table. Take another look at exactly how the carry output is generated.

Comment: @DaveTweed I can't seem to figure out whats wrong.

Comment: And, your table only has 9 states.  This counter counts from 0000 to 1111 -- sixteen states.  Your table doesn't show Count Enable.  While we are assuming it is 1, this should be shown, or at least specified.

Comment: Look at the Present State in that last line (of your original table). Why did you assign the value 1 to Output Carry? Also, if you want to add more information, use the `edit` button below your question. The answer area is reserved for answers.

Comment: Is your new chart showing next state for B0-B3?  Not correct, but closer.  You have skipped some states after 11 (1011).  Also, look at Carry Out.  This is the AND of Count Enable and Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3.